# How to tell program to stop until query is over?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing on swift. I have a method with query which takes time and I need to stop the method until the query is done. What code should I write?

```
  func fetchNearestPlace (coord: CLLocation) -> [PlaceMarker] {
    var returnArray: [PlaceMarker] = [];
    self.dataProvider.fetchPlacesNearUser(coord.coordinate, radius: 40) { places in
      self.placesOnTheWay = [];
      for place: GooglePlace in places {
        let marker = PlaceMarker(place: place);
        returnArray.append(marker);
        println(marker.place.name);
      }
      println("Query for places around user");
    }
    return returnArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work that way.

You made the fundamental error of thinking that you can call an asynchronous method and return its result. It doesn't work.

Change your method name to "startFetchingNearestPlace" which makes clear what it does: It doesn't fetch the nearest place, it starts the process, which will finish at some point.

When the process is finished, your completion block needs to do all the things that need doing to process the information that you downloaded.